# Travis-Ci unable to run node with --harmony-proxies flag

Tags: travis-ci

How are people getting by with builds that require passing the `--harmony-proxies` **flag**? I am testing with Ava which requires I do this, but Travis gives me this response:

```
to be executed: node_modules/.bin/nyc node --harmony_proxies ./node_modules/.bin/ava 
/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v6.5.0/bin/node: bad option: --harmony_proxies
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, figured it out. The problem was with Node 6.5. The build works all the way up to 6.3 at least. Just had to change our Travis config to run a lower version.